# What is .wsuo file?

Tags: c#, commit, gitignore, suo

In my project, while cloning existing repository, there is immediately added one new file.
What is that? Am I allowed to push it or should I ignore it in .gitignore?

[image: screenshot]

There already exists .suo file...
Could the reason be that I have installed the newest Visual Studio version?

Comment: `.vs` itself should be in your `.gitignore`... you shouldn't need to worry about anything within it.

Comment: ignore the .vs-folder. that folger contains solution and project settings generated by visualstudio. this folder saves what files you upened last and where you posititioned your windows.

Answer (score 3):

From official MS [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/internals/solution-user-options-dot-suo-file?view=vs-2022):

> The solution user options (.suo) file contains per-user solution options. This file should not be checked in to source code control.

The solution user options file is used to store user preference settings, and is created automatically when Visual Studio saves a solution. So need to worry. Even if you delete this, it will be auto generated on the very next build.

Moreover, it should not be checked into source code. So in your `.gitignore` file, you should its reference as well:

```
.wsuo
```

Comment: OK thanks, I was confused because I knew that .suo exists, but never saw .wsuo and why it shows when I didn't change a thing

Comment: I am not sure.Could be due to the latest update maybe. Which version of VS you're using btw?

Comment: I am using 17.4.1 on desktop, where is .wsuo file when cloned. But on my laptop, with some older version, is .suo when I clone the same repository. That's why I think that the problem is in VS version

Comment: Yeah seems like it can be a issue/bug with the VS version. If this answer helped, you can mark it as accepted.